# Wave rider function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, riemann-zeta, periodic-functions

I'm looking for an example of a 'wave-like' function $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

- deterministic
- smooth (continously differentiable)
- periodic but with varying period lengths $p_i$, $p_i \neq p_j$
- mean period length $p=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=-n}^n p_i$ is finite but not $0$ (periods don't get constantly larger or smaller)

I tried various combinations of sine functions but that seems more tricky than I thought.

A non-trivial example might be the Riemann zeta function (normalized to have unit [average spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture)), i.e., $f(x) = \text{Re}\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+\mathsf{i} \delta(x))$.

*Background:* The question is related to how random the roots of a deterministic function can be?

Answer (score 1):

I think $\displaystyle f(x) = \sin\big(x + 10\sin\big(x^{\frac{3}{5}}\big)\big)$ should work.

[image]

It has a vertical tangent at $x=0$ because $x^{\frac{3}{5}}$ is not differentiable there, but it satisfies all of your other conditions. In particular, the period varies but never goes to $0$. (I think it averages out to $2\pi$ because the second term's influence lessens over time, but I'm not sure.) You could fix the vertical tangent issue by using a differentiable-everywhere function in place of $x^{\frac{3}{5}}$, which would have to be sublinear so the period doesn't go to $0$.

On a sidenote, I found this function while playing around, which I think looks pretty cool.

$f(x) = \sin\big(x+\sin\big(x^{2}\big)\big)$

[image]

Comment: Nice find, the distribution of period lengths has a peak around $\pi$.

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: Numerically, using Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a function like $\sin(x\arctan(x))$ since the periods get shorter as you aproach infinity but never aproach 0.

Comment: Good idea. I had a more irregular behavior in mind, like a water wave.

Comment: Water waves are [c-noidal waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnoidal_wave).